# Ошибка при получении AccessToken

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При вызове функции fetch с данным url [https://api.vk.com/method/auth.exchangeSilentAuthToken?v=5.131&token=silent_token&access_token=service_token&uuid=uuid"](https://api.vk.com/method/auth.exchangeSilentAuthToken?v=5.131&token=silent_token&access_token=service_token&uuid=uuid%22) возвращается ошибка "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." Попробовал передать "mode: no-cors", ошибок нет, но функция возвращает пустое тело. Если данный url вызвать через адресную строку браузера все работает без проблем т.е. получаю AccessToken. В чем может быть проблема?